# How to append L to variable name

Tags: java, long-integer

Say I have this variable: `long l = 2000000000;` I then want to create a new variable `long l2 = l*l;`  This would not return the proper value as `l*l` is just too large. I know I have to append `L` to those very very big long numbers, but how do I do it when using variables to get to a very big `long`number?

Comment: It does return the proper value, `l*l` is not too large. Appending an 'L' to a constant only affects the interpretation of that constant. If you have some code that isn't working then post the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only multiply two `int`s you should cast them to `long` before multiplying. `long l2 = ((long) l) * ((long) l).`

If l is already a `long` (as in your case) you do not have to cast.

Integers larger than `Long.MAX_VALUE` can be handled with `BigInteger`.

You can not multiply large longs and expect to get a long that is greater than `Long.MAX_VALUE`. In this case you should also use `BigInteger`